# Get last insert rowid using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've created a UWP app with a sqlite database using the [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite?view=msdata-sqlite-3.0.0) library. After inserting a new row, I need to know the autoincrement value assigned to the new row. The code below uses the additional query "select last_insert_rowid()", but is there a better way to obtain this value?

```
public static int AddMovie(Movie movie)
{
    string dbpath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, DB_FILENAME);
    using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection($"Filename={dbpath}"))
    {
        db.Open();

        SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand();
        cmd.Connection = db;

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (NULL, @Title, @Rating)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", movie.Title);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", movie.Rating);

        cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Is there a better way to get this value?
        cmd = new SqliteCommand("SELECT last_insert_rowid()", db);
        SqliteDataReader query = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        var newId = 0;
        if (query.Read())
        {
            newId = query.GetInt32(0);
        }

        db.Close();

        return newId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could combine both queries into a single command, and instead of calling `cmd.ExecuteReader()` call `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` and convert the returned value to `int`:

```
public static long AddMovie(Movie movie)
{
    string dbpath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, DB_FILENAME);
    using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection($"Filename={dbpath}"))
    {
        db.Open();

        SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand();
        cmd.Connection = db;

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (NULL, @Title, @Rating); SELECT last_insert_rowid();";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", movie.Title);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", movie.Rating);

        return (long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Note: Raycoon's answer points out some drawbacks of this solution.

Comment: That is a little simpler, although I had to cast to a long, not an int. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial way of retrieving the rowid (by separating the insert and select command) is more appropriate and more "secure". **Combining the INSERT and SELECT commands will ignore unique constraint violations** when inserting data in your table (in case you have a unique index). You will simply get "0" as new rowid - and no exception will be thrown!

Using separate commands results in SqliteExceptions when data cannot properly be inserted in your table. Therefore I wouldn't use the second, "correct" approach. Better use your initial code - but **ExecuteNonQuery** for **INSERT** and **ExecuteScalar** for **SELECT last_insert_rowid()**.